# How to Delete Item from Observable collection in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone app and I want to delete item from listbox.

I am using following code
 List numbers=new List();

```
 ObservableCollection<string> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(numbers);
        int indexPerson = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
        myCollection.RemoveAt(indexPerson);
        var my = (ObservableCollection<string>)listBox1.ItemsSource;
        listBox1.ItemsSource=my;
```

and when I click on delete button one item is deleted based on index and then when I will delete another item the previously deleted item is show and current deleted item is deleted.

How can I delete all items?

Comment: `how i can delete all item please help me`? Set `myCollection` to null, write `myCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>()`? Use the `ClearItems()` function ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654925%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), iterate though each item in the collection and remove it manually... May choices here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear all items you can just use

```
myCollection.ClearItems()
```

if you want to remove just selected item than use

```
 myCollection.Remove(Listbox1.Selecteditem)
```

Comment: Guy Levin sir i want delete item one by one not all item at a time

Comment: Can you post more of your code? I think something is wrong with your perception of observable collection

Comment: I think something is wrong with your perception of observable collection, can you post more of your code?